# How can I remote test an Orchard tenant running on local IIS?

Tags: iis, orchardcms

I use Visual Studio 2013 and IIS 10.

Usually when I'm developing an Orchard website, I test it locally by adding an alias to my Windows hosts file and then adding a binding for that alias in IIS, e.g.

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite
```

IIS:

```
Type     | Hostname    | Port   
------------------------------
http       mysite        80
```

When I want to test on a different device I add a binding for some arbitrary port, eg `666`, to the website in IIS without specifying a hostname. Then I open that port so I can reach it from my phone or tablet on the local network by browsing to `http://mycomputer:666`. Or if I want to show it to someone else I can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get a temporary public URL for that port.

But how can I get a port to take me to a tenant that's running under the same website instead?

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite
127.0.0.1 mytenant
```

IIS:

```
Type     | Hostname    | Port   
------------------------------
http       mysite        80     // I can reach the master locally at http://mysite
http       mytenant      80     // I can reach the tenant locally at http://mytenant

http                     666    // mycomputer:666 takes me to mysite
                                // How to get it to take me to mytenant?

http       mytenant      666    // This doesn't work, invalid hostname error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have in your hosts
`127.0.0.1 local.site.com` & `127.0.0.1 local.tenant.com`
Then in IIS set host name as `local.tenant.com` at **xxx** port

Comment: If I do this I can reach `local.site.com` and `local.tenant.com:xxx` but simply going to `local.tenant.com` just shows me the default IIS page and trying to reach it via `mycomputer:xxx` still gives me an invalid hostname error. Could this be a problem with my configuration?

Comment: I realised I can test the tenant by specifying an URL prefix like `/tenant` and then I can reach it through `mycomputer:xxx/tenant`. This is sufficient for my requirements at the moment, but I'll continue to try and get separate hosts working.

Comment: local.tenant.com you need a new binding on 80 port